# Display number of found products in layered navigation

Tags: layered-navigation

I want to display the total number of currently found/selected above/inside the layered navigation.
In the templates `catalog/layer/view.phtml` or `catalog/layer/state.phtml`

I tried:

```
/* @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $_category */
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
var_dump($_category->getProductCount());
```

And a few other functions that are in the class but none seem to give the number I need.
Anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get

```
$select = clone Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection()->getSelect();
```

Then you can modify the `$select` object to get COUNT() and fetch it.

Note, you have the right collection with all filters applied after the render of `catalog/layer/view block`.

You need to use clone, as later magento will use the same collection for pager and product list.

Comment: I found `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection()->getSize()` which returns a `int` of the products. Do I still need to clone? It doesn't look like it affects anything.

Comment: If it works fine and does not affects the product listing it's OK.